# Getting the name attribute of a HTML check box(and other elements) in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to get the name of check boxes so that i can group all check boxes with the same name,  i have tried `cb.Name` (`cb` is a object of type  `HtmlInputCheckBox`) this only returns the id, i also have tried `cb.Attributes["name"]` which also gives nothing. Not sure any other ways to get the name attribute of a check box any body else have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work around the way ASP.NET renders the name attribute, you might want to  remove the `runat="server"` from the input tags in your markup. That way the tags will be rendered as they are in the markup an won't be processed by the HtmlInputCheckBox class. You can get the values of the checkbox by using `Request.Form["nameOfCheckbox"]` in a postback event.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign same [GroupName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862473.aspx) to all the checkboxes property to group them.

```
cb1.GroupName = "SomeName";
cb2.GroupName = "SomeName";
```

Comment: There is no attribute called `GroupName` for an object of type `HtmlInputCheckBox` so i can't set this.

Comment: Okay, why to you not use CheckBox? try can you check if you get cb.Name?